# Cleancache backend implementation

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel

I'm trying to play with cleancache making a back-end for it.
The thing is, I'm not sure why my backend ops are not being called.

My module source code can be [viewed here](https://gist.github.com/muriloadriano/d5343a50e802dea8d868).

The only `printk`s that I can see on dmesg are:

```
>> ZCOMPRAM INIT
>> ZCOMPRAM: cleancache_enabled
```

But none of the `printk`s in the cleancache operations are called.

Comment: What's the filesystem you are using ? Does it have support for cleancache ? Is cleancache being used ? What's the behaviour when stock cleancache is used without your module ?

Comment: @VivekS I believe the problem is that the YAFFS does not support cleancache, but I will investigate.

Comment: @VivekS It should be simple to add support to YAFFS2. I saw for example in EXT3 the only thing related to cleancache is a `cleancache_init_fs(sb);` call in `ext3_setup_super()`. The thing is that in YAFFS there is no `setup_super` like function. :(

Comment: See this link...I think it adds support for cleancache in YAFFS https://github.com/nobodyAtall/msm7x27-2.6.32.x-nAa/blob/master/fs/yaffs2/yaffs_vfs.c#L2996

Comment: Thanks @VivekS, I did that before and now I get it to call my `init_fs` op. I was lucky to put that call in the exactly same place the link you posted :). But there are other function calls there that I didn't do. Thanks.